# Why the same contract has more bytecode size in solidity 0.5 in compare to 0.4.24?

Tags: solidity, evm, solc, compiler

My earlier contract was compatible with solc@0.4.24. Now I am upgrading my contract to make it compatible with solidity 0.5 but it leads to an increase in bytecode size. AFAICT There is no change in the EVM. solidity 0.5 is the only high-level change. It shouldn't affect the EVM but increase in the bytecode size is questionable.

Comment: I think for someone to help with this, they'd have to see the code so they could compare the compiled output.

Comment: It is possible that a bug fix or a new feature causes an increase in the generated bytecode because extra checks have to be done.